# How to measure data usage of my app

Tags: android, networking, 3g

I'm developing an Android app which needs to download a lot of data.

To improve the usability, I'd like to measure the data traffic my app produces and give the users a hint if the app downloaded a specific amount of data.

My current idea: Sum all downloaded bytes together and react on a specified limit. However, as I downloaded things in many different situations and in many different positions in the code, is there any other possibility to measure the data usage per app?

AFAIK, `sys/net/NETINTERFACE/statistics/rx_bytes` reports the total amount of the whole system, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> However, as I downloaded things in many different situations and in many different positions in the code, is there any other possiblity to measure the data usage per app?

[`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) may be able to report things by UID. I say "may" because it seems tied to devices. I suspect that Android 3.0+ will consistently report by UID, but my 2.2 and 2.3 experience has been mixed.

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/Bandwidth/TrafficMonitor) demonstrating recording this information.

Comment: can we get application data usage by wifi and mobile both??

Comment: @Erick: Yes, `TrafficStats` reports WiFi and mobile data separately.

Comment: but for particular application ?

Comment: @Erick: Ah, that's not supported, sorry.

Comment: Link expired. :(

Comment: @kolboc: Thanks for pointing that out! I have updated the link to a better one.